# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined al querer sacar el total

Tags: php, javascript, poo

Buen día.

A la hora de agregar el impuesto no puedo sacar el total, me da el siguiente error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

lo que quiero realizar es la suma en tiempo real de la columna total

```js
     function modificarSubototales()
      {
        var cant = document.getElementsByName("cantidad[]");
        var prec = document.getElementsByName("precio[]");
        var sub = document.getElementsByName("subtotal");
        var tot = document.getElementsByName("total");
        var imp = document.getElementsByName("impuestos[]");
        var res = document.getElementsByName("resultado");

        for (var i = 0; i <cant.length; i++) {
            var inpC=cant[i];
            var inpP=prec[i];
            var inpS=sub[i];
            var inpI=imp[i];
            var inpT=tot[i];
            var inpR= res[i];
            inpS.value=inpC.value * inpP.value;
            inpR.value=inpS.value * inpI.value;
            inpT.value=inpS.value + inpR.value;
            document.getElementsByName("total")[i].innerHTML = inpT.value;
        }
        calcularTotales();

      }
      function calcularTotales(){
        var sub = document.getElementsByName("total");
        var total = 0.0;

        for (var i = 0; i <sub.length; i++) {
            total += document.getElementsByName("total")[i].value;
        }
        $("#total").html("" + total);
        $("#total_compra").val(total);
        evaluar();
      }
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Es raro que trates a `inpS, inpR, inpT` como elementos del DOM que tendrían una propiedad `value`, cuando no son otra cosa que variables que creas dentro del `for`. Si es como pienso, ``inpS, inpR, inpT` tendrían en sí los valores que quieres obtener invocando a `value`.

Comment: @A.Cedano entonces que recomiendas hacer?

Comment: Sólo te doy pistas sobre dónde podría estar el error. Si no conozco tu contexto no puedo  recomendarte nada, por eso en las preguntas siempre es bueno explicar un poco lo que intentas hacer. No sé que es `cant`, ni qué quieres hacer en ese `for`, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya actualice la pubicacion

Comment: Para este caso las imágenes no sirven de mucho. Si he entendido bien, lo que quieres es sumar los totales de una serie de filas ¿cierto? Pues a los elementos que guardan esos valores podrías darle una clase y luego usar ese selector para hacer la suma. Creo que te estas complicando demasiado.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas con capturas de pantalla en lugar de código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Edita tu pregunta, elimina la imagen y pega el código. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.